# ¿Cómo ejecutar un comando CMD (Windows) desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cmd

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente, que he buscado y aún no encuentro solución, espero alguien me pueda dar una pequeña luz.

El asunto es que, mi respaldo de la base de datos la realizo en Windows, y para ello tengo que ir al CMD para ejecutar la línea de código para que me realice el respaldo.

Mi objetivo es que, desde mi aplicación PHP en el botón "respaldar", al dar clic me haga el respaldo con el código. He probado con anterioridad en JAVA, sin embargo, PHP no me quiere hacer caso alguno.

¿Alguien podría darme una mano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con

```
exec("ipconfig");
system("ipconfig");
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!